# How to scale/rotate small trackers with mouse?

Tags: tracking

I'm working on a motion tracked animation, but I'm running into trouble trying to rotate and move small trackers independently of the search area. Usually, I would do this by clicking on the square on the far right, but this doesn't work so well for very small trackers, because when I try to click on it, instead it selects one of the corners of the tracker itself, so I can't rotate/scale it. I understand that I can move the whole tracker using the <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>R</kbd> and <kbd>G</kbd> hotkeys, but I want to be able to adjust the tracking area independently of the search area. How can I do this?

[image: small tracker]

Comment: Have you tried using the Circle Select? Just press [C]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can zoom in using the scroll wheel on the mouse until the tracker becomes large enough to manipulate.

[image]

The track area and the search area can be manipulated separately. Enable "Search" on the Marker Display section to make the search area visible. Then you'll be able to manipulate them to your needs.

[image]